# What components to use when connecting to a mySQL Database on a webserver

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2

I, want to develop an application that can access my database on my website. I want to know what components can I use to access, insert and update records in my database. Im using a mySQL database on a unix server. The application will be running in windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without understanding well what you mean by what components you need (other than TDataset et all), all I can do is to refer you to this article:

- [How to set up the dbGo (ADO) ConnectionString for mySQL database](http://delphi.about.com/od/mysql/qt/mysqladoconn.htm)

If you have some cash available, I heartily recommend you get the [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) components. I've heard that the [DevArt](http://www.devart.com/) components are also good, but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend http://www.devart.com/unidac/ very easy to setup and it supports multiple databases.

We've been using them for over 2 years and we're very comfortable with it.

Answer (score 3):

[AnyDac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) is the best and it's definitely worth buying. I've had plenty of experience with multiple components (AnyDac,UniDAC,SQLDirect,SDAC) and AnyDac has proved its value.

In comparison Anydac is faster, you have the ability to scale up your application to N-tier, supports more systems, has Free Pascal support.